# if $\alpha$ is trascendental over K then $f(\alpha)$ is also trascendental over K?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Consider the field extension $(L:K)$ and $\alpha \in L$ trascendental over K. Let $f(x) \in K[x]$ a not-constant polynomial, then $f(\alpha)$ is also trascendental over $K$.
I was thinking of supposing that $f(\alpha)$ is algebraic, then $\exists g(x)\in K[x]$ s.t.  $g(f(\alpha))=0$, then , can i compose to say $(g\circ f)(\alpha)=0\equiv h(\alpha)=0$ meeting a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what you can do. You just have to show that $h$ is not constant, and that it is a polynomial, and you're done.

Explicitly, you've shown $f(\alpha)$ algebraic $\implies$ $\alpha$ algebraic. No contradictions or anything here. Just the contrapositive of the statement you were originally asked to solve. Since contrapositives are equivalent, you're done.

Comment: okay, i asked just in case because i was not sure about composing abstract polynomials as they were functions

Comment: @ArmandoRosas You can definitely compose them. Say you have two abstract polynomials $f(x) = 1 + x^2 - x^3$ and $g(x) = 3+4x$, then $f(g(x)) = 1 + (3 + 4x)^2 - (3 + 4x)^3$ makes total sense and is a polynomial regardless of whether $x$ is an abstract symbol or represents an "unknown" element of $K$.